# Can banshees regenerate armor?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've been trying to wear down the couple of Banshees in the Asari Monastery. Even if I remember wearing down the barriers, the base health, its 'armor' keeps coming back... is that just my illusion or does Armor regenerate (like barriers)?

Comment: I don't recall them ever doing that, unless you have to wait a loooong time for it to start regening

Comment: I never saw something like that. They can regen barrier, but they don't like my widow full of damage mods. ;-))))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know they can regenerate their barriers, but I've never seen a banshee regen her armor as well.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad. I was just confusing between the two. One would cloak itself and become invisible, so I was looking at the healthier one I did not attack yet.

Answer (score 0):

I read on the wiki that they just have very high armour and barrier and they regenerate by getting on there knees and screaming so yes they do.